# GIT: how to connect a second local repository with an existing GitHub repository?

Tags: git, github

I am learning to handle the GIT repositories.
I have a repository on GitHub and I have cloned it locally. I have modified some files, then add -A, commit -m and git push origin master. So far so good.

Now, I have created another local repository with Git GUI, I have placed the files of the site-web (django 2.0), and again add, commit, after:

```
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/Frank-Mascarell/LibrosWeb.git
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/Frank-Mascarell/LibrosWeb.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/Frank-Mascarell/LibrosWeb.git (push)
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
$ git fetch origin


$ git push origin master
To https://github.com/Frank-Mascarell/LibrosWeb.git
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Frank-
Mascarell/LibrosWeb.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

and I have also tried:

```
$ git pull origin master
From https://github.com/Frank-Mascarell/LibrosWeb
* branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

Why are you giving these errors?
It seems that the two repositories are not well connected, and I can not upload or download.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have created a new repository from scratch, and you have added a remote to that.

In the first scenario, you are trying to push changes to a branch which does not share the same history as your branch.

In the second scenario, you are trying to merge changes from the remote branch into your branch. This fails because the two branches do not share any common history.

If you instead start over and instead of initialising a new repository, make sure you clone the original one and start from there. This will allow you to both push new changes, and to merge or rebase on top of existing commits.

Answer (score 0):

The error message gives a clue as to the issue. The two repositories have unrelated histories.

In git, you aren't solely dealing with files and changes to files, though that is what you are getting out of it. Each commit in git contains a reference to every commit that lead up to it, giving you a full and complete history of how things got to be the way they are.

What happened is you have three repositories, two are linked, and one was created brand new but given identical files.

So your repository started on github, and then was cloned down locally, and you can push and pull back and forth, mirroring not just the data but the entire commit history. They both have a complete reference of your project from start to finish.

The new repository just has a snapshot of the most recent state of the project, without any history.

It's possible to modify your new local repository to get it into a state where it can push to an existing branch again, but it's probably more complicated than necessary.

The easiest thing to do is just to clone the new repository again, either from github or from your first local repository.

However, if you have changes you've already made to the second local repository, you'll want to copy those changes into one of your cloned repositories, make new commit(s) and push from there.

Comment: There were errors:

$ git log --oneline master
ea885d3 (HEAD -> master) Testing GitHub
e61b038 Nueva versión con entorno virtual

$ git checkout -b new-master origin/master
Switched to a new branch 'new-master'
Branch 'new-master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'origin'.

Comment: $ git cherry-pick ea885d3 e61b038
error: could not apply ea885d3... Testing GitHub
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'

Comment: $ git push origin new-master:master
Everything up-to-date

Comment: $ git status
On branch new-master Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
You are currently cherry-picking commit ea885d3.(fix conflicts and run "git cherry-pick --continue")  (use "git cherry-pick --abort" to cancel the cherry-pick operation) Unmerged paths:(use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution) both modified:   LibrosWeb/settings.py no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

Comment: $ git checkout master
error: you need to resolve your current index first
LibrosWeb/settings.py: needs merge

$ git cherry-pick --continue
error: Committing is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.
U       LibrosWeb/settings.py

Comment: You can use git cherry-pick --abort to get out of it and try again.

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit unclear. The very first commit to the repository shouldn't include your changes, so you'll want to leave that out unless there are changes in it. I'll edit the answer to make that clearer. You can use git cherry-pick --abort to get out of it and try again. If its' still giving you these errors, what's happening is you have a merge conflict. Open the file up in a text editor and look for the <<<< old version ---- new version <<<< areas, and resolve them. Some editors make this easier.

Comment: I think I will make some necessary comments regarding git.
For many developers who do not need a team of developers, as is my case, the use of git is unnecessary. Version control can be easily managed with simple local backups, and uploading the necessary hosting through a protocol provided by the service provider.

Now, I'm researching possible hosts for Django that do not require git, like Heroku, Digital Ocean, PythonAnyware, it seems that they need git to be able to work. Any suggestions? or Any other possible provider?

I take this opportunity to thank Ira Casper for her great help.

Comment: Sorry, I was a little afraid I was being overwhelming with all of the options. Git is a very powerful tool that lets you do a lot of very clever and sometimes complicated things with your projects. The simple answer to your question was to just use git clone <your github> again, and make your changes from there. If you were to drop in the files from your 'lost' repository, and make a new commit, that would work just fine, and all three repositories would be in sync by pushing and pulling.